# Cassandra Async write batch :Want to check data of which Cassandra Batch failed

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra Batches to write to in Cassandra Nodes
The batch size is 20.

```
   List<List<SimpleStatement>> lists = Lists.partition(simpleStatementList,20);
  List<ListenableFuture<CompletionStage<AsyncResultSet>>> futures = new ArrayList ();
  try{
      lists.forEach(list -> {
       BatchStatementBuilder batchStatementBuilder =
                      BatchStatement.builder(BatchType.LOGGED);
       list.forEach(batchStatementBuilder::addStatement);
       futures.add(executorService.submit(() ->
            session.executeAsync(batchStatementBuilder.build())));
   });
   }catch{
     LOG.error("Error")
   }finally {
       Futures.allAsList(futures).get(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
       futures.forEach(val -> {
       try {
        val.get().whenCompleteAsync(
                (resultSet, error) -> {
                  if (error != null) {
                    LOG.info("Fail to write Cassandra");
                  }
                });
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    });
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

I want to know which Batches are failed when I write using Async method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please hover over, or click on the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, then after you've determined that this question has nothing to do with a script using the extension `.bat` or `.cmd`, as run on Windows, please remove it!

Comment: are you just combining multiple inserts/updates/deletes into a batch? Or you're doing something else?

Comment: Those are all insert statements in one table

Answer (score 0):

Within your code, you can catch the exception returned from the asynchronous request and handle it whichever way you want. For example, log the contents of  the `lists` object.

As a side note, CQL batches are not an optimisation. In fact, they are expensive and will perform worse than separate asynchronous statements since they put pressure on the coordinator.

Given that you are bulk-inserting into the same table, this is bad practice and is not recommended in Cassandra. CQL batches are for achieving atomicity when updating the same record in multiple tables. Cheers!